# Grab image from server in ios

Tags: ios, image

I've seen that you can download an image in IOS through a URL. However, this requires that the URL be public. I'd much rather do it in such a way where my application makes a request to the server and if the necessary requirements are met, the server responds with an image. I do not want my images to be visible from the web.

Comment: Send parameters with the request and/or make the user log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to put the password in the URL:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://exapmle.com/2XwLZAgAO2VP9JqXg1s73zmB/foo.png")
let dataOptional: NSData? = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)

if let data = dataOptional {
  let image = UIImage(data: data)
} else {
  println("Error loading \(url)")
}
```